# LINQ to SQL datetime mismatch on var dbSVJOB = _context.SVJOB.Find(jobIds.JobId);

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am working with a DB Model multi-layered web application and am finally stuck on this one last problem with handling dates between c# and sql.

I have found answers to pulling in dates from SQL to String with Linq queries.
I can use string format to add or update SQL dates from c#.

But when I execute this Find in order to retrieve an existing row to before Save Changes

var dbSVJOB = _context.SVJOB.Find(jobIds.JobId);

Linq or Entity sees the System.DateTime from the DB and says it cannot match is with the string version in my DB model.
Error is:
"The 'DateCreate' property on 'SVJOB' could not be set to a 'System.DateTime' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'. "

I have tried to do some manipulation on the Table Model Get accessor and have had no luck with .HasColumnType with OnModelCreating, as well.

I do not really need to get the date in this application. I just need to set DateCreate and DateUpdate.

I do not have more than a years experience with c#. But have made this pretty major application I designed, work. Many years in the IBM mainframe world.

Thanks for any advise you can offer.

Comment: Why not use one of the [SQL data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) for a date? You may need to show what you have done so far as a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, [here are some conventions on C# naming](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards).

Comment: I am sure why I started out having problems using another data types. think .HasColumnType("smalldatetime"); is going to work for me along with DateTime data type on the Model definition.

Comment: Did not get the edit in time. Here is the final comment.                                    I am not sure why I started out having problems using a data type beside string. DateTime data type on the Model works fine for me, now. And I do not need to use the .HasColumnType("smalldatetime"); on the OnModelBuilding, but this is valid where others date notations were not recognized. DateTime.Now work fine as is. It took off the AM PM and added milliseconds automatically. I guess I got caught up in other postings talking about having troubles and using strings to solve.